# Azure elastic cloud with private endpoint

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-private-link

Currently, I'm utilizing Elastic Cloud on Azure and aiming to secure it through Private Link.

I've established a private endpoint with a private DNS zone in Azure and incorporated a DNS forwarder.

However, when I ping "elastic-name.kb.privatelink.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com," I receive the private IP.

Yet, when pinging "elastic-name.kb.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com," I get the public IP, which differs from the typical behavior of Azure resources.

I've tested other resources like blobs, files, and app services, and consistently received private IPs for both.

Do you have any insights into why Elastic behaves in this manner?

Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Trying to use private link for all connections to my azure elastic search

Answer (score 0):

As per [official document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-traffic-filtering-vnet.html) Elastic Cloud through private link by default once you create traffic filter for your private link endpoint on the elastic cloud portal when elastic approves your private link endpoint. you can only access the endpoint with a private link route like `elastic-name.kb.privatelink.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com`

Added virtual network link as well as DNS A record for the private endpoint's IP address as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Now to access Elasticsearch cluster through Private Link you can use only below URL structure.

```
https://{elasticsearch_cluster_ID}.{private_hosted_zone_domain_name}:9243
```

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/qYeY08M.png)]

***Reference***:

[Secure your deployments on Elastic Cloud with Azure Private Link | Elastic Blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/secure-your-deployments-on-elastic-cloud-with-azure-private-link)